# Error message - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: nodes, routes, users

i'm getting a notice

> Error message - Trying to get property of non-object

here's my function:

```
<?php
function func()
{
        $node = menu_get_object();
        global $user;
        if ($node->type == 'hall' &&
            in_array('instructor', array_values($user->roles)))
        {
            return " hall-instructor ";
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what `node_get_object()` returns since it could not return an object. This is particularly true when the user is not watching a node page, but even in the case the viewed page is a node one, the function could not return an object. This is why Drupal code always check the returned value.

```
function book_page_alter(&$page) {
  if (($node = menu_get_object()) && !empty($node->book['bid'])) {
    $active_menus = menu_get_active_menu_names();
    $active_menus[] = $node->book['menu_name'];
    menu_set_active_menu_names($active_menus);
  }
}
```

```
// template_preprocess_page()
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $variables['node'] = $node;
}
```

```
// template_preprocess_html()
// If on an individual node page, add the node type to body classes.
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('node-type-' . $node->type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not preparing node object & trying to access that. Your are using  menu_get_object(), which returns node ID only. So something like this should work -

```
<?php
function func()
{
     $nid = menu_get_object();
     $node = node_load($nid);
     global $user;
     if ($node->type == 'hall' && in_array('instructor', array_values($user->roles))) {
         return " hall-instructor ";
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: No, `menu_get_object()` returns a `stdClass` object, when called for the right menu item.