# Trying to get property of non-object throws exception that cannot be handled

Tags: 8

In a custom Drupal 8 module I decided to wrap a line of code in a try...catch block, in case $node was null.

I understand that in php errors and exceptions are different, and according to [Error message - Trying to get property of non-object](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167538/error-message-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object) this is an error, so will not be handled by try...catch, and the code should continue to run after the error.

However when this code runs under Drupal 8 the error hander raises an exception. So I added the try...catch block. But the exception is still unhandled crashed the program.

This is a cut-down version of my code:

```
$node = null;
try {
  // The next line results in an unhandled exception 
  $f = $node->field_example;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Never gets here
  watchdog_exception('example', $e);
}
// Never gets here
```

Am I missing something? Surely this can't be the intended behaviour?

Comment: Yes, that’s the behaviour PHP intends; it has exceptions and errors as you say, and fundamentally misusing a data type is an example of an error. To avoid, use `instanceof`, `is_object` or similar

Comment: It's explained in [Errors in PHP 7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php). _As the `Error` hierarchy does not inherit from `Exception`, code that uses `catch (Exception $e) { ... }` blocks to handle uncaught exceptions in PHP 5 will find that these Errors are not caught by these blocks. Either a `catch (Error $e) { ... }` block or a [`set_exception_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) handler is required._

Comment: You can also just `catch (\Throwable $e)` if you want both

Comment: Thanks @Clive that works.

Answer (score 2):

I actually over-simplified by question. The crash doesn't happen in the simple case I posted, just an error and execution continues. It arises when I use field API syntax to refer to a null referenced entity, and only then when the target_id is not null.

```
$node->field_foo->target_id = 999; // term 999 does not exist
try {
  // The next line results in an unhandled exception 
  $v = $node->field_foo->entity->field_bar->value;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Never gets here
  watchdog_exception('example', $e);
}
// And never gets to continue here
```

The issue was why and Drupal does this. The solution (thanks @Clive) is to replace `catch (\Exception $e)` with `catch (\Throwable $e)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to catch `Exception`, when you should be catching `\Exception`.

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
```

EDIT: Assuming that an exception is actually thrown as stated in the original post.